# The tetralemma based languages

Tags: list-of-languages

The tetralemma system of logic ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetralemma)
evaluates each proposition into four possible values which are true ,false ,neither true or false and both true and false.

Are there languages which explicitly have words specific to  the above?

(I mean words specific to the evaluation of propositions and particularly the last two values -- since true and false must already be there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know everything about truth in 6000+ languages of the world, I doubt that there exists any language with a tetralemmatic truth system.

Even the meaning of "true" and "false" in natural spoken English does not match its logical interpretation; the logicians' use is kind of a specialised terminology one has to learn.

Comment: The language where in it was probably first expounded in and that was by Buddha in Pali... The language itself lacks these words... So probably U are right.But then can some expert in Pali correct me.